# Java equivalent for Python's toordinal()?

Tags: java, python, datetime, epoch, ordinal

What is the best way to replicate `datetime.datetime.now().toordinal()` in java?
I tried using epoch but the results are nowhere near.

Comment: Can you post what you tried and the result?

Comment: Here's the source of [`toordinal()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a9b47b062b9/Lib/datetime.py#l57); you'll likely just want to port this to Java if you really need this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to query that information using the Java Time API but you can calculate it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long ordinal = LocalDate.now().toEpochDay() + (146097 * 5L) - (31L * 365L + 7L);

    System.out.println(ordinal);
}
```

Run today, 19th April 2016, it outputs `736073`, which is consistent with Python's output.

From a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), you can get the Epoch day with [`toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--). If you take a look [inside the current implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/time/LocalDate.java#LocalDate.toEpochDay%28%29), you'll find that it actually calculates the total number of days since year 0 and subtracts that with the constant

```
static final long DAYS_0000_TO_1970 = (DAYS_PER_CYCLE * 5L) - (30L * 365L + 7L);
```

where `DAYS_PER_CYCLE = 146097` is the number of days in a 400 year cycle. That constant isn't public, so we can't reuse it directly.

From the Python documentation of [`toordinal()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal), it defines year 1 to have an ordinal of 1. The calculus above by the Java API supposes that it is year 0 instead so we just need to adjust for that.